# Number of parallel instances of my process (app)

Tags: c++, process

Is there some portable way to check the number of parallel instances of my app?

I have a c++ app (win32) where I need to know how often it was started. The problem is
that several user can start it parallel (terminal server), so i cannot search the "running process" list because I'm not able to access the the list of other users.

I tried it with Semaphore (boost & win32 CreateSemaphore) 
It worked, but now I have the problem if the app crashes (Assertion or just kill the process) the counter is not changed. (rebooting helps)

Also manually removing/resetting the semaphore counter in my code is not possible because I don't know if somebody else is running my application.

Comment: Do want to know the exact number, or do you only care if the number is 0 or >= 1?

Comment: What do you need this for? As you already noticed, it's not going to be very reliable, because processes might disappear before decrementing the counter.

Comment: How many instances of your application are running or how many times was started and finished?

Comment: I presume this is to enforce some licensing scheme, so the goal would be to know how many instances are actually in use at any given moment.

Comment: Yes its for licensing purposes, I would x instances to run with full feature set, all other instances should only allow reduced functionality
This works so far but if one instance crashes, the semaphore is not reduced and I loose an "licence" until next reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to add:

Suppose you have a license that lets you run 20 full-functionality copies of your program.  Then you could have 20 mutexes, named MyProgMutex1 through MyProgMutex20.  At startup, your program can loop through the mutexes.  If it finds a spare mutex that it can take, it stops looping and enters full-functionality mode.  If it loops through all the mutexes without being able to take any of them, then it enters reduced-functionality mode.

Original answer:

I assume you want to make sure that only one copy of your process runs at once.  (Or, for Terminal Server, one copy of your process per login session).

Your named semaphore solution is close.  The right way to do this is a named mutex.  Use [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make the mutex, then call [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a timeout of zero.  If WaitForSingleObject returns WAIT_TIMEOUT, another copy of the process is running.  If it returns WAIT_OBJECT_0 or WAIT_ABANDONED, then you are the only copy of the process.  You need to keep the mutex handle open while your program runs - either call [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when your process is about to exit, or just deliberately leak the handle and rely on Window's built-in cleanup to release the handle for you when your process exits.  Windows will automatically increment the mutex's counter when your process exits.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specifiy it better
I want to know the number of running instances, 
mutex alone is not enough.

Comment: The WAIT_ABANDONED looks promising, but it don't work with Semaphores. There WaitForSingleObject always returns timeout oder success.

Comment: I implemented it with win32 semaphore.
It automaticly  deletes the handle (semaphore) if no process is using it any longer, so no rebooting is needed, only to close all instances of my app and start again from the beginning 
this behaviour is **good enough** for my purpose

Only problem is, its not portable but we take on this issue when we actually port the code to another system :-).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that mitigates the problem of crashed processes is a kind of [“dead man’s switch”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch): each process needs to update its status in regular intervals. If a process fails to do this, it’s automatically discarded from the list of active processes.

This technique requires that one of the processes acts as a server which keeps tab of whether other processes have updated recently. If the server dies, then another process can take over. This, in turn, requires that each process tests whether there still is a server alive.

Alternatively, each process can be its own server and keep track locally. This may be easier to implement than server-switching.

Answer (score 1):

You can broadcast message and other instances of your application should send some response. You count responses - you get number of instances.